# sonatype nexus p2 repo cannot retrieve artifacts.xml & content.xml from local storage

Tags: eclipse, maven, nexus, equinox, p2

I have received a source code and an instruction to configure local p2 and maven repositories in sonatype nexus, copy repo files to sonatype-work/nexus/storage and to run mvn install in the subfolders in the specific order. Maven repositories work fine, but although the p2 metadata files exist in the correspoing folder on the drive (artifacts.jar artifacts.xml content.jar and content.xml), the nexus cannot find them resulting in the following error logged in nexus.log (I have changed the domain to companyname.com) :

```
2018-09-18 14:54:54,672+0200 DEBUG [qtp1268488730-105] anonymous org.sonatype.nexus.plugins.p2.repository.proxy.P2ProxyMetadataSource - Repository eclipse-luna: retrieve item: /artifacts.xml: took 30881 ms.
2018-09-18 14:54:54,672+0200 DEBUG [qtp1268488730-105] anonymous org.sonatype.nexus.plugins.p2.repository.proxy.P2ProxyRepositoryImpl - eclipse-luna retrieveItem() :: NOT FOUND eclipse-luna:/artifacts.xml
2018-09-18 14:54:54,672+0200 DEBUG [qtp1268488730-105] anonymous org.sonatype.nexus.plugins.p2.repository.proxy.P2ProxyRepositoryImpl - Proxy repository 'eclipse-luna' is is not allowed to issue remote requests (BLOCKED_MANUAL), not adding path '/artifacts.xml' to NFC
2018-09-18 14:54:54,673+0200 WARN  [qtp1268488730-105] anonymous org.sonatype.nexus.plugins.p2.repository.proxy.P2ProxyRepositoryImpl - Could not retrieve list of repository mirrors. All downloads will come from repository canonical URL.
org.sonatype.nexus.plugins.p2.repository.proxy.P2RuntimeExceptionMaskedAsINFException: Item not found for request "ResourceStoreRequest{requestPath='https://COMPANYNAME.COM/nexus/content/groups/eclipse-luna/content.xml', requestContext=RequestContext{this=org.sonatype.nexus.proxy.RequestContext@3f86d772, parent=null}, pathStack=[], processedRepositories=[], appliedMappings={}}" in repository ""Eclipse - Luna" [id=eclipse-luna]"!
    at org.sonatype.nexus.plugins.p2.repository.proxy.P2ProxyMetadataSource.doRetrieveContentFileItems(P2ProxyMetadataSource.java:195)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.plugins.p2.repository.proxy.P2ProxyMetadataSource.doRetrieveContentFileItems(P2ProxyMetadataSource.java:56)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.plugins.p2.repository.metadata.AbstractP2MetadataSource.doRetrieveContentItems(AbstractP2MetadataSource.java:399)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.plugins.p2.repository.metadata.AbstractP2MetadataSource.doRetrieveItem(AbstractP2MetadataSource.java:307)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.plugins.p2.repository.proxy.P2ProxyRepositoryImpl.doRetrieveItem(P2ProxyRepositoryImpl.java:419)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.proxy.repository.AbstractRepository.retrieveItem(AbstractRepository.java:760)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.plugins.p2.repository.proxy.P2ProxyRepositoryImpl.retrieveItem(P2ProxyRepositoryImpl.java:390)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.proxy.repository.AbstractRepository.retrieveItem(AbstractRepository.java:592)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.plugins.p2.repository.proxy.P2ProxyRepositoryImpl.configureMirrors(P2ProxyRepositoryImpl.java:188)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.plugins.p2.repository.proxy.P2ProxyRepositoryImpl.doRetrieveItem(P2ProxyRepositoryImpl.java:430)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.proxy.repository.AbstractRepository.retrieveItem(AbstractRepository.java:760)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.plugins.p2.repository.proxy.P2ProxyRepositoryImpl.retrieveItem(P2ProxyRepositoryImpl.java:390)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.proxy.repository.AbstractRepository.retrieveItem(AbstractRepository.java:592)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.proxy.router.DefaultRepositoryRouter.retrieveItem(DefaultRepositoryRouter.java:155)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.content.internal.ContentServlet.doGet(ContentServlet.java:386)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.content.internal.ContentServlet.service(ContentServlet.java:352)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.ServletDefinition.doServiceImpl(ServletDefinition.java:297)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.ServletDefinition.doService(ServletDefinition.java:281)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.ServletDefinition.service(ServletDefinition.java:186)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.AbstractServletPipeline.service(AbstractServletPipeline.java:65)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:85)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:112)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:82)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.AbstractFilterPipeline.dispatch(AbstractFilterPipeline.java:100)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.web.internal.NexusGuiceFilter$MultiFilterChain.doFilter(NexusGuiceFilter.java:82)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:89)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.AbstractFilterPipeline.dispatch(AbstractFilterPipeline.java:100)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.web.internal.NexusGuiceFilter$MultiFilterChain.doFilter(NexusGuiceFilter.java:82)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:89)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.AbstractFilterPipeline.dispatch(AbstractFilterPipeline.java:100)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.web.internal.NexusGuiceFilter$MultiFilterChain.doFilter(NexusGuiceFilter.java:82)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:89)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ProxiedFilterChain.doFilter(ProxiedFilterChain.java:61)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.executeChain(AdviceFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.doFilterInternal(AdviceFilter.java:137)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ProxiedFilterChain.doFilter(ProxiedFilterChain.java:66)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.executeChain(AdviceFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.doFilterInternal(AdviceFilter.java:137)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ProxiedFilterChain.doFilter(ProxiedFilterChain.java:66)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.executeChain(AdviceFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.doFilterInternal(AdviceFilter.java:137)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ProxiedFilterChain.doFilter(ProxiedFilterChain.java:66)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.executeChain(AbstractShiroFilter.java:449)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.web.internal.SecurityFilter.executeChain(SecurityFilter.java:90)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter$1.call(AbstractShiroFilter.java:365)
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.doCall(SubjectCallable.java:90)
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.call(SubjectCallable.java:83)
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.DelegatingSubject.execute(DelegatingSubject.java:383)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractShiroFilter.java:362)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:82)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.AbstractFilterPipeline.dispatch(AbstractFilterPipeline.java:100)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.web.internal.NexusGuiceFilter$MultiFilterChain.doFilter(NexusGuiceFilter.java:82)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:89)
    at com.yammer.metrics.web.WebappMetricsFilter.doFilter(WebappMetricsFilter.java:76)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:82)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.web.internal.CommonHeadersFilter.doFilter(CommonHeadersFilter.java:69)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:82)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.web.internal.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:71)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:82)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.web.internal.BaseUrlHolderFilter.doFilter(BaseUrlHolderFilter.java:66)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:82)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.web.internal.HeaderPatternFilter.doFilter(HeaderPatternFilter.java:96)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:82)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.AbstractFilterPipeline.dispatch(AbstractFilterPipeline.java:100)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.web.internal.NexusGuiceFilter$MultiFilterChain.doFilter(NexusGuiceFilter.java:82)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.web.internal.NexusGuiceFilter$MultiFilterPipeline.dispatch(NexusGuiceFilter.java:56)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter$1.call(GuiceFilter.java:133)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter$1.call(GuiceFilter.java:130)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter$Context.call(GuiceFilter.java:203)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter.doFilter(GuiceFilter.java:130)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1476)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:501)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:557)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1086)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:429)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1020)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
    at com.yammer.metrics.jetty.InstrumentedHandler.handle(InstrumentedHandler.java:200)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:154)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:370)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:494)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:971)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1033)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:644)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:696)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot write metadata repository. Reason: Communication with repository at https://COMPANYNAME.COM/nexus/content/groups/eclipse-luna/ failed.
    at org.sonatype.p2.bridge.internal.MetadataRepositoryService.createProxyRepository(MetadataRepositoryService.java:313)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.plugins.p2.repository.proxy.P2ProxyMetadataSource.doRetrieveContentFileItems(P2ProxyMetadataSource.java:187)
    ... 100 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core.ProvisionException: Communication with repository at https://COMPANYNAME.COM/nexus/content/groups/eclipse-luna/ failed.
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.CacheManager.createCache(CacheManager.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.SimpleMetadataRepositoryFactory.getLocalFile(SimpleMetadataRepositoryFactory.java:66)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.SimpleMetadataRepositoryFactory.load(SimpleMetadataRepositoryFactory.java:88)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.MetadataRepositoryManager.factoryLoad(MetadataRepositoryManager.java:57)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.helpers.AbstractRepositoryManager.loadRepository(AbstractRepositoryManager.java:749)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.helpers.AbstractRepositoryManager.loadRepository(AbstractRepositoryManager.java:651)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.MetadataRepositoryManager.loadRepository(MetadataRepositoryManager.java:96)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.MetadataRepositoryManager.loadRepository(MetadataRepositoryManager.java:92)
    at org.sonatype.p2.bridge.internal.MetadataRepositoryService.createProxyRepository(MetadataRepositoryService.java:283)
    ... 101 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:668)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:178)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:432)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:527)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(HttpsClient.java:264)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:367)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:191)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1138)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1032)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:177)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:153)
    at org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.browse.URLFileSystemBrowser.runRequest(URLFileSystemBrowser.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.browse.AbstractFileSystemBrowser$DirectoryJob.run(AbstractFileSystemBrowser.java:69)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
```

and when try to run mvn install I got the error:

```
[INFO] Adding repository http://127.0.0.1:8081/nexus/content/repositories/eclipse-luna
[ERROR] Failed to resolve target definition /home/creotech/.m2/repository/COMPANYNAME/maven/Eclipse-Luna/1.0.0-M1/Eclipse-Luna-1.0.0-M1.target: Failed to load p2 metadata repository from location https://COMPANYNAME.COM/nexus/content/groups/eclipse-luna/: No repository found at http://127.0.0.1:8081/nexus/content/repositories/eclipse-luna. -> [Help 1]
```

I can open in a browser http://127.0.0.1:8081/nexus/content/repositories/eclipse-luna and I see the files and folders:

- binary
- features
- plugins
- artifacts.jar
- artifacts.xml
- content.jar
- content.xml

and I can open subfolders and I can download files in subfolders from the browser but I cannot download any file in the root (artifacts/content jar/xml) due to the error:

```
404 - Item not found for request "ResourceStoreRequest{requestPath='https://COMPANYNAME.COM/nexus/content/groups/eclipse-luna/content.xml', requestContext=RequestContext{this=org.sonatype.nexus.proxy.RequestContext@c1bae82, parent=null}, pathStack=[], processedRepositories=[], appliedMappings={}}" in repository ""Eclipse - Luna" [id=eclipse-luna]"!

Item not found for request "ResourceStoreRequest{requestPath='https://COMPANYNAME.COM/nexus/content/groups/eclipse-luna/content.xml', requestContext=RequestContext{this=org.sonatype.nexus.proxy.RequestContext@c1bae82, parent=null}, pathStack=[], processedRepositories=[], appliedMappings={}}" in repository ""Eclipse - Luna" [id=eclipse-luna]"!
```

I tried to change timeout times in the list of repositories in nexus as well as in Administration > Server, but it did not helped. To ensure it is not an issue with a file permission, I have changed permissions to 777 and run nexus as root but it also did not helped. Also, I tried to run tasks Rebuild P2 metadata and Rebuild P2 repository at this repo and next at all repos, but in both cases the problem stayed the same. Upgrade from nexus-2.14.0-01 to 2.14.9-01 also have not changed anything the same as increment of java max memory in the wrapper.conf. Any ideas how to solve it?

Arek

Answer (score 0):

if someone will have a similar problem - a hosted site repository solved the problem above